# Ideas to refactor code with many Lists

Tags: android

I need a little help to get an idea of how to refactor my code, but I can't see options besides what's done, I would like to add the objects but not using so many lists (and if's conditions).

Here is my code, if anyone could help, I appreciate. Thanks

```
@ViewById
BannerHomeViewPager place1, place2, place3, place4, place5, place6, place7,
        place8, place9;
```

The lists:

```
private List<HomeItem> allHomeItems = new ArrayList<HomeItem>(),
        placeItems1 = new ArrayList<HomeItem>(),
        placeItems2 = new ArrayList<HomeItem>(),
        placeItems3 = new ArrayList<HomeItem>(),
        placeItems4 = new ArrayList<HomeItem>(),
        placeItems5 = new ArrayList<HomeItem>(),
        placeItems6 = new ArrayList<HomeItem>(),
        placeItems7 = new ArrayList<HomeItem>(),
        placeItems8 = new ArrayList<HomeItem>(),
        placeItems9 = new ArrayList<HomeItem>();
```

1) Items mocked, ok.

2)

```
@UiThread
void updateUI() {

    if (allHomeItems != null && allHomeItems.size() > 0) {

        for (HomeItem item : allHomeItems) {
            if (item.getPlacement().contains("1")) {
                placeItems1.add(item);
            } else if (item.getPlacement().contains("2")) {
                placeItems2.add(item);
            } else if (item.getPlacement().contains("3")) {
                placeItems3.add(item);
            } else if (item.getPlacement().contains("4")) {
                placeItems4.add(item);
            } else if (item.getPlacement().contains("5")) {
                placeItems5.add(item);
            } else if (item.getPlacement().contains("6")) {
                placeItems6.add(item);
            } else if (item.getPlacement().contains("7")) {
                placeItems7.add(item);
            } else if (item.getPlacement().contains("8")) {
                placeItems8.add(item);
            } else {
                placeItems9.add(item);
            }
        }

    }
    setupAdapters();
}
```

3) `setupAdapters()`

```
private void setupAdapters() {

    if (place1 != null)
        place1.update(placeItems1);

    if (place2 != null)
        place2.update(placeItems2);

    if (place3 != null)
        place3.update(placeItems3);

    if (place4 != null)
        place4.update(placeItems4);

    if (place5 != null)
        place5.update(placeItems5);

    if (place6 != null)
        place6.update(placeItems6);

    if (place7 != null)
        place7.update(placeItems7);

    if (place8 != null)
        place8.update(placeItems8);

    if (place9 != null)
        place9.update(placeItems9);
}
```

Comment: maybe use a hashmap to wrap up the lists, and use placement as key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DanielBo answer:

```
private Map<String, ArrayList<HomeItem>> placeItems = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<HomeItem>>();



  void updateUI() {
        if (allHomeItems != null && allHomeItems.size() > 0) {
             for (HomeItem item : allHomeItems) {
                if(!placeItems.containsKey(item.getPlacement())){
        placeItems.put(item.getPlacement(), new ArrayList<HomeItem>());
                }
        placeItems.get(item.getPlacement()).add(item);
             }
        }
       setupAdapters();
  }
```

But why are you using so many views? I really can't say if this is correct bcs i don't know the purpose of this, but I can't figure a good use to so many list views in the same layout...

Comment: @LeonardoLeonardo no problem, but now I'm curious about why you have so many views on your layout :P , can you give me a light?

Comment: sure... I dont know if you'll understand my explanation, because I'm new to android. Anyway, there are some animations in the Activity, each Banner will receive 3 pictures and these pics are being loaded from 4 to 4 seconds. But, client did not send the real images, so we had to mock many things...

Comment: You could also use a custom ListView with 3 columns with a custom adapter to do that :D